# tcl search and replace multiple occurances

Tags: search, replace, tcl

I have multiple lines in html file containing:

```
xxxxxx"./FSsacdss12s.tcl.html#::FSxxxxt_15" target="main">::FSxxxxxt</a></dt>
xxxxxx"./FSsacdss12s.tcl.html#::FSxxxxt_15" target="main">::FSxxxxxt</a></dt>
xxxxxx"./FSsacdss12s.tcl.html#::FSxxxxt_15" target="main">::FSxxxxxt</a></dt>
```

I would like to search and remove all occurrences of FS from each line, resulting in:

```
xxxxxx"./sacdss12s.tcl.html#::xxxxt_15" target="main">::xxxxxt</a></dt>
```

I have tried:

```
set ToLft_ "^|\./|\[^a-zA-Z]|\::"
set ToRght_ "\[^a-zA-Z]|$" 
regsub -all ($ToLft_)FS($ToRght_) $line "" line
```

Without any success.. Any suggestions is very much appreciated!

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`string map`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M38) to replace all occurrences of "FS" with an empty string:

```
set line [string map {FS ""} $line]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
regsub -all "FS" $line "" line
```

Comment: Thanks for the `-all`.